# Sourcemap from multiple bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack-2, source-maps

I have a main app `foo` with `webpack2` which bundles some node_modules. One of the module is a `bar` which is also bundled with webpack2 with sourcemaps.

I used to have `bar` bundle injected into `foo` index.html as a separate script and sourcemaps were working fine in devtools.

Now `foo` is bundling `bar` and other node_modules together into a `vendor` bundle and that gets injected into index.html. In devtools I can see only the whole `vendor` bundle with sourcemap for all libraries.

Is there a way of having my `bar` bundle sourcemap appended somehow so I could treat that bundle separately and see the folder structure in devtools?

With current setup I can see in devtools only `bar.bundle.js` but I would like to see more granular like I had initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loader seems to do the trick!

```
rules: [{
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: ['source-map-loader'],
  enforce: 'pre',
},
```